# How to display a custom view in Android?

Tags: android

I am generating a custom View that contains a number of drawables that are added to the View dynamically. This means the View's size could be anything, and is likely to stretch off the screen. Where it does stretch off the screen I want scrolling to be enabled.

So far I have tried:

- adding the custom view directly to my `Activity` - this displays the drawables ok, but with no scrolling
- adding the custom view as a child to a `ScrollView` and setting the `ScrollView` as the content in the `Activity` - this doesn't display anything.

How do I generate a custom view of arbitrary size, display it and have scrolling where it is too big for the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it to a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) should be fine. Remember:

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning
>   you should place one child in it
>   containing the entire contents to
>   scroll; this child may itself be a
>   layout manager with a complex
>   hierarchy of objects. A child that is
>   often used is a LinearLayout in a
>   vertical orientation, presenting a
>   vertical array of top-level items that
>   the user can scroll through.

To make sure your "custom view" is working fine, first try to add a `LinearLayout` to the `ScrollView` and then add drawables to the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: thanks got it working, i also had to set FillViewPort = true in the ScrollView. I also had to wrap a HorizontalScrollView in the ScrollView to enable bi directional scrolling..

Comment: @flesh Thanks you "FillViewPort" works for me, thanks once again